# How to get Title Value by Clicking List Item With a Class Used by Multiple List Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, title

In my web application, I have the following list items:

```
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#3100ff" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#9330ff" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
<li class="ui-corner-all" title="#500055" style="border: none; background-color: rgb(144, 0, 255);"></li>
```

When I click a list item with the class "ui-corner-all", I am trying to get that list items title value (e.g. if I clicked the first list item, I would get the value `#3100ff`.

Is this possible via JavaScript/Jquery? If so, does anyone know the code I could use for this endeavor?

Off the top of my head, I'm thinking something like:

`

```
if ((".ui-corner-all").attr("title").click()) {
var title = (".ui-corner-all").attr("title");

alert(title);
}
```

`

Although, this does not work.

Thank you for reading my question, and for any help you may provide.

Comment: you need to write an onclick handler and get the title of the current element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were fairly close, although that's not how you handle events in javascript and you forget the `$` in front of your jquery calls:

```
$(".ui-corner-all").on('click', function(){
   var title = $(this).prop("title");
   alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply with:

```
$('.ui-corner-all').click(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('title'));
});
```

The problem with your attempt is you're invoking the `click` event rather than assigning a handler for it. Also you missed the jQuery `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(".ui-corner-all").click(function(){
     var title = $(this).attr("title");
     alert(title);
});
```